# Finding column and row space without computing A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have the a question that asks that I find the column space and row space of:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2 \\4&5 \\2&7\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3&0&3 \\1&1&2 \end{bmatrix}$$

What I was thinking of doing was row reducing the matrices and to get $LU$ but when I do that I am unable to get a correct matrix. I know that it should be a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Is there another way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you multiplied the matrices?

Comment: yes but I am not allowed to compute A.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A=A_1A_2$ where $A_1$ is the $3$ x $2$ matrix that you have on the left, and $A_2$ is the other matrix.

Then column space of $A$ is contained in the column space of $A_1$. Can you claim that they are equal?

Comment: I understand what you mean but I do not know how to claim that. Would I multiply by using column represntation multiplication?

Comment: @user081608: use some "rank" argument. Note that rank($A_1A_2 \leq $ rank$A_1$ or rank$A_2$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $c_1,c_2$ be the columns of the first matrix and let $r_1,r_2$ be the rows of the second matrix.

Then the columns of A are given by $\{3c_1+c_2, c_2, 3c_1+2c_2\}$, so the column space of A is given by

$span\{3c_1+c_2, c_2, 3c_1+2c_2\}=span\{c_1,c_2\}$ $\;\;\;\;\;$(since $c_1=\frac{1}{3}(3c_1+c_2)-\frac{1}{3}c_2$).

Similarly, the rows of A are given by $\{r_1+2r_2,4r_1+5r_2, 2r_1+7r_2\}$, so the row space of A is given by

$span\{r_1+2r_2,4r_1+5r_2, 2r_1+7r_2\}=span\{r_1,r_2\}$ $\;\;\;$

$\;\;\;$(since $r_1=-\frac{5}{3}(r_1+2r_2)+\frac{2}{3}(4r_1+5r_2)$ and $r_2=\frac{4}{3}(r_1+2r_2)-\frac{1}{3}(4r_1+5r_2)$).